# Cassette.web, MVC 3, Shared Layout: Get references in the right order?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, cassette

Using Cassette.net, MVC 3, Razor, C#, relative locations, and shared layouts, how do you get references in the right order without modifying the original javascript files?

In the shared layout, I reference jQuery like this:

```
Bundles.Reference("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js");
```

Then in the view I add another reference:

```
Bundles.Reference("~/Scripts/myScript.js");
```

myScript depends on jQuery, yet Cassette references myScript in front of jQuery:

```
<script src="/_cassette/asset/Scripts/js/myScript.js?...
<script src="/_cassette/asset/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js?...
```

I find it odd that scripts referenced in child pages render before parent page scripts.

I see you can add notations to your scripts, e.g., `/// <reference path="other.js" />` but I really don't want to modify javascript code to include this.

**Update:**

I added

```
Bundles.Reference("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js","head")
Bundles.Reference("~/Scripts/js/myScript.js","body")
```

which at least puts my script after the jQuery script using `@Bundles.RenderScripts("head");` and `@Bundles.RenderScripts("body");` within the appropriate tags.  It seems to keep the scripts in the order added.  I'd still like to know how to custom order these scripts with some type of Bundle.config or how to get parent pages to order scripts before child pages using Shared Layouts.

Comment: The comment notation is the proper way to achieve this to the best of my knowledge. You also mentioned the overload that takes a location. Personally, I don't see the drawback to the comment approach. You're not functionally changing the javascript library and you actually get a dependency graph of sorts to work with.

Comment: I haven't found a way to order scripts even with comments when some Bundles.Reference happen in the parent and child layouts.  It always puts the child references first it seems.  For example, jQuery referenced in the parent layout/view follows after the script tags in the child view, failing because jQuery wasn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [bundle descriptor file](http://getcassette.net/documentation/v1/configuration/bundle-descriptor-file). You can then force the file order.